# Can docker write to a cd?

Tags: ubuntu, docker

Can docker write to a cd? Can docker execute

```
cdrecord dev=/dev/sr0 -checkdrive
```

from a Ubuntu container?

Docker seems to be able to use the parent's network hardware, so why can't it use the parents cdrom/DVD device?

Update:

This question is about programming in that I have some shell script that I run on my Ubuntu VM and I want to know if it is feasible to migrate to docker.  I apologize for not pointing this out initially :)

Comment: with `--privileged`?

Comment: sorry I do not understand your comment. Does you mean,"yes docker can write to a CD if you specify `--privileged` as a option to the cdrecord command? Please I am a docker noob and have specific use case.

Comment: Try `docker run --privileged` on whatever image you are using.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suppose so (not tested yet), you can find an example in this [`docker run` script](https://github.com/MarvAmBass/docker-handbrake/blob/master/run-handbrake.sh):

```
docker run \
-t --rm \
--privileged \
-v $XSOCK:$XSOCK \
-v /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro \
-v /dev/sr0:/dev/sr0 \
-v /dev/cdrom:/dev/cdrom \
-v $RIPS:/rips \
--name handbrake marvambass/handbrake &
```

As mentioned [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29934903/can-docker-write-to-a-cd/29934960#comment47991877_29934903) by [Luca](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2173133/luca), the `--privileged` flag is required ([`docker run`](http://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#run)):

> by default, most potentially dangerous kernel capabilities are dropped; including `cap_sys_admin` (which is required to mount filesystems). However, the `--privileged` flag will allow it to run.
>
> The `--privileged` flag gives *all* capabilities to the container, and it also lifts all the limitations enforced by the device `cgroup` controller.
>   In other words, the container can then do almost everything that the host can do.
>   This flag exists to allow special use-cases, like running Docker within Docker.

---

As [Vincent Demeester](https://stackoverflow.com/users/89249/vincent-demeester) mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29934903/can-docker-write-to-a-cd/29934960?noredirect=1#comment48070928_29934960), there is also the `--device` option:

> It is often necessary to directly expose devices to a container. The `--device` option enables that.
>   For example, a specific block storage device or loop device or audio device can be added to an otherwise unprivileged container (without the `--privileged` flag) and have the application directly access it.
>
> By default, the container will be able to read, write and `mknod` these devices. This can be overridden using a third `:rwm` set of options to each `--device` flag
>
> **Note**: `--device` cannot be safely used with ephemeral devices. Block devices that may be removed should not be added to untrusted containers with `--device`.

As seen in [issue 10637](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/10637), some devices can change their node names. See [issue 8826](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/8826)

> If you launch the Docker daemon with the `lxc` backend, you should be able to use `--lxc-conf=lxc.cgroup.devices.allow = c 189:* rwm` to allow your container to access all devices of that group, and then use a `volume -v /dev/bus/usb/:/dev/bus/usb/` to access *all* USB devices.

Comment: There is also a ``--device`` flag to the run command : ``--device=[]                Add a host device to the container`` which should be better to use than a *file volume*

Comment: @VincentDemeester good point. I have included it in the answer for more visibility.